# Possibly dereferencing NULL in C

Tags: c, null, linked-list, malloc, pointer-arithmetic

I'm traversing a list of nodes which have two fields: next and size. There comes a point in the code where I need to link in a new node and I am having trouble. I've found where the code seg faults and it looks like this. Note that curr is the current node in the list and I need to link in temp between curr and curr->next.

```
    Node* temp = NULL;
    temp = ((curr + 1) + a_memory_offset_int);   //calculate the address where temp should go

    temp->next = curr->next;      //Seg faults here
    temp->size = some_other_int; //Seg faults here as well

    curr->next = temp;
```

Is there some way that I am trying to set the fields for a NULL node? Is there something wrong with the syntax (as I am confident the logic is correct)?

Comment: post more code. and run it through valgrind and gdb as a rule

Comment: It is not possible to set a value in the field of NULL. I There seems to be a problem with the pointer arithmetic of that before. Please note that it is carried out in the pointer size pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY But I don't think it is NULL because the line after I set it to be NULL, i change the value inside temp to be after the address of the previous node. I get what you're saying about the pointer sized arithmetic which is why I do (curr + 1) instead of (curr + sizeof(Node)). Thanks for the input though

Comment: Any time you're doing pointer arithmetic you're on your own.  I suspect you've got some misconceptions at work here, since pointer arithmetic (beyond incrementing through an array) is rarely needed.

Comment: no, no, `A_memory_offset_int` the sources of problems rather `+1`?

Comment: If anything it would be the +1 because memory_offset is just an int

Comment: `curr + 1` is separated `sizeof(Node)` the address refers to the next node. temp address is `&curr[1 + A_memory_offset_int]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code, I suspect you might not understand what `a_memory_offset_int` is doing. It's doing the exactly same thing as the `+ 1`, that is to say that it's doing pointer arithmetic. This:

```
temp = ((curr + 1) + a_memory_offset_int);
```

is equivalent to:

```
temp = (Node*)(((char *)curr + 1*sizeof(Node)) + a_memory_offset_int*sizeof(Node));
```

What you probably really want is:

```
temp = (Node*)(((char *)curr + 1*sizeof(Node)) + a_memory_offset_int);
```

Note the only difference is the multiplication of `a_memory_offset_int` by `sizeof(Node)`. More simplified, this is what you want:

```
temp = (Node*)((char *)curr + a_memory_offset_int) + 1;
```

Comment: But, really, you need to post complete code for us to fully understand your intentions.

Comment: This worked. I was thinking that only the curr + 1 have been affected by the scaling factor of sizeof(Node). I didn't realize the whole expression was affected including the addition of the size (which is just supposed to be a raw number of bytes no scaling needed).

Answer (score 1):

A linked list node's memory address isn't really important - you shouldn't be calculating it yourself, and instead calling malloc, then linking it in.

Something more like this:

```
Node* temp = NULL;
temp = malloc(sizeof(Node)); // create a new node, allocating fresh memor

temp->next = curr->next;     // should be fine now...
temp->size = some_other_int;

curr->next = temp;
```

Comment: this is actually in an implementation of malloc() i am calling Mem_Alloc() so i can't call malloc, unfortunately.

Comment: It does work if I use malloc() but the point of my specialized implementation is to calculate the addresses in memory where everything should be.

Comment: Ah, I see. The other thing that comes to mind is your memory offsets might be in bytes, but the arithmetic may not be. curr + 1 sill be of type Node*, and then adding the offset to it could be shooting you sizeof(node) times further than you thought. Might help to cast them all to unsigned char* if the offsets are in bytes.

Comment: Right that's what I want. So what we have is a block in memory with a header and a data portion. The header (what we are keeping track of as nodes) has the size of the data portion and the address of the first byte of the next header. So ((curr + 1) + size) should give me the address of the first byte where I want to put my new node i called temp. But when i try to change the fields in temp to set up the new header, it seg faults.

Comment: Just did. That seg faults as well. If i convert it to a char, would i then have to add the sizeof(Node) or just keep it as 1? If i convert it to a char which is 1 byte, i dont think it will add enough.

Comment: it also gave me the warning when compiling "initialization from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: The warning is expected here - the cast makes it count in chars then it is assigned back to a Node*, you'd explicitly cast it back once the calculation is correct. But, What is a_memory_offset_int too? It could be calculated wrong or be a strange type.

Comment: No that is an int. Immediately following the header is the data space. The size of this space is given in the header as the 'size' field which is just how many bytes (as a multiple of 4) the data space has. immediately following this data space is the header for the next block in memory. So it will look like header-data-header-data-header-data...so shouldn't the start of the next header be (if curr is the first byte of the current header) ((curr + 1) + size)?

Comment: This is the code I wrote for a similar thing that works just now: `toUse->next = (Node*)((unsigned char*)(my_malloc_root + 1) + nBytes);` I counted nBytes by one. So root + 1 moves past the header. Then it is cast to unsigned char* so the next addition does bytes. Then I add bytes, and finally cast the whole thing back to Node* to silence the warning. If your memory offset is in multiples of four... I'd still do the casting and just do offset*4 there. I didn't spend too much time on this but this little program shows my thing doing the basics: http://arsdnet.net/test.c

Comment: @AdamDRuppe That code helped me very much in tracing my own and figuring out how to fix my problem. What i didn't realize that the + size at the end was being scaled by sizeof(Node) instead of just being a raw number of bytes. Thanks very much for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sample program for verification of pointer arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int size;
    struct node * next;
} Node;

int main() {
    void *memory = malloc(10*sizeof(Node));//allocate of Node * 10
    Node *curr = memory;
    Node *temp = NULL;

    temp = curr + 1;
    temp->size = 999;
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(Node));
    //16
    printf("%p,%p\n", (void*)curr, (void*)temp);
    //00000000004D67B0,00000000004D67C0 <- difference is 16
    int a_memory_offset_int = 16;
    temp = curr + a_memory_offset_int;
    if(temp > &curr[9])//curr[9] is last element
        printf("It is outside the allocated memory\n");//this display
    temp = curr + a_memory_offset_int/sizeof(Node);
    printf("%d\n", temp->size);//999

   return 0;
}
```